# <'WebDriver'>.switchTo().frame(<'frameId'>) not working with Chrome driver

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, selenium, webdriver

Need to access elements inside a modal iframe.

Below code works perfectly fine for FireFox driver while fails for Chrome -

```
String frameId = null;
List<WebElement> frameSet = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));  
for (WebElement frameName : frameSet){  
    if(!(frameName.getAttribute("id").isEmpty()) && (frameName.getAttribute("id").contains("DlgFrame"))){
            frameId = frameName.getAttribute("id");
        }
}

try {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

Logger.info("Switch to Frame - "+frameId);
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id(frameId)));
```

Does Chrome driver support switchTo.frame(<'frameId'>)?

Error while using Chrome Driver -

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unknown command. Options: ActivateTab, CaptureEntirePage, CloseTab, DeleteCookie, ...
>
> Command duration or timeout: 220 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time: '2012-07-18 22:18:01'
>   System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_05'
>   Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
>   Session ID: cbde65cb0394ee0434b3bb528918ce40
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:188)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:498)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:244)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:87)
>       at com.shn.services.Office365.sharePointUploadFile(Office365.java:173)
>       at com.shn.test.RunOffice365Test.testSharePointUploadAndDeleteFile(RunOffice365Test.java:55)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:74)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:92)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:180)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:350)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1021)

Comment: In 2021 chromedriver seems to still have issues with the switchTo command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was neither with chromeDriver nor selenium. Both were running on latest versions.

chromeDriver - 23.0.1240.0

Selenium - 2.25.0

The issue was with Chrome Browser.

My browser was running on ver. 12.0.742.112.
Automatic updates were failing due to -

> update Server not available (error:7)

I had to uninstall & install back the browser to get it to the latest ver. 21.0.1180.89 m.

The issue is now fixed & I am able to switch between frames.

Answer (score 9):

ChromeDriver supports switchTo since it implements the WebDriver Interface.
It works fine for me.

You have to do it like this:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("frameId")));
//do your stuff
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: Yes, I am using Selenium 2.25.0 & chomeDriver version 23.0.1240.0. I understand that webDriver supports switchTo. But does it support switchTo FrameId specifically?

Comment: Above code results in same error. Even tried including some waits before switching to frame. No effect.

Comment: that should work... hmm your exception shows that you are using selenium 2.24.1?

Comment: That was earlier. But I am getting the same issue post upgrading to 2.25.0. Updated the log section of original post. Are there some chrome parameters that I should explicitly set to get it working with frames?

Comment: nope. i ve been using that code for month now with chrome and never had any problems

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will help anyone, but I was having a similar issue polling frames and this is what the solution was for me.

Switch to DefaultContent():

```
_driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

Get the frames:

```
IWebElement iFrames = _driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//iframe"));
```

Poll through the frames, but only switch to it if "Displayed" is true:

```
foreach (var frame in iFrames)
{
    if (!frame.Displayed)
        continue;

    _driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frame);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem not in the iframe. Error listing includes `org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:87) at`. 
So I assuming another part of your code leads to app. fail.

Comment: Seems like the OP found the crash to be Chrome's fault.

Answer (score 1):

This is my implementation of switching to frame for all browsers, because switching to frame by Id or Name doesn't work for Chrome (with latest versions)

- using Xpath (more elegant/readable code):

```java
/**
 * This switch to frame method improves standard way to switching to frame
 * ( driver.switchTo().{@linkplain org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.TargetLocator#frame(String) frame(String nameOrId)} )
 * because Chrome browser has problem with this method.   <br/>
 *
 * Bug: http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=107
 * @param frameIdOrName the id or name of the &lt;frame&gt; or &lt;iframe&gt; element
 * @return This driver focused on the given frame.
 */
public WebDriver switchToFrameByIdOrName(String frameNameOrId) {
    if (driver instanceof ChromeDriver) {
        String frameElementXpath = String.format("//frame[@name='%1$s' or @id='%1$s']", frameNameOrId);
        WebElement f = driver.findElement(By.xpath(frameElementXpath));
        return driver.switchTo().frame(f);
    }
    return driver.switchTo().frame(frameNameOrId);
}
```

or

- using CSS selectors (because CSS selectors should be faster way for finding elements. For more infos see [Selecting WebDriver locators](http://darrellgrainger.blogspot.sk/2011/12/selecting-webdriver-locators.html):

```java
public WebDriver switchToFrameByIdOrName(String frameIdOrName) {
    if (!(driver instanceof ChromeDriver)) {
        return driver.switchTo().frame(frameIdOrName);
    }
    WebElement frame = null;
    try {
        frame = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("frame[id='" + frameIdOrName + "']"));
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) { /* It's ok for the moment */  }

    if (frame == null) {
        try {
            frame = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("frame[name='" + frameIdOrName + "']"));
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            log.severe(String.format("CORE > switchToFrameByIdOrName() error: Frame with name or id '%s' not found.", frameIdOrName));
        }
    }
    return driver.switchTo().frame(element);
}
```

I'm using:

```
Selenium 2.37.1
Session info: chrome=31.0.1650.57)
Driver info: chromedriver=2.7.236900,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64
```